# A question from Hilbert and Courant's Vol II of Methods of Mathematical Physics (I might have spotted an error).

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations

In page 751 (I hope some folks have a copy of it, legal or otherwise, I have a legal one :-D), I am attaching scans of pages 750-751.
http://www.mediafire.com/view/?7hu91s2t5866lqj

http://www.mediafire.com/view/?hndt9uy5e2gh29a

(I tried to upload it from my computer but failed to do so).

Anyway, I don'tunderstand two things, the equation in page 751, the RHS of $u(x_0,0,0,t_0)$, in $\psi$, shouldn't the x-component be $\alpha t_0/2 + x_0$? and in the second term shouldn't it be just $\alpha t_0 \psi_x$?

Here is my reasoning, the x-component should be calculate according to Lorentz transformation in page 750:

$$x = \frac{t_0}{\sqrt{t_0^2-x_0^2}} (\frac{\alpha}{2}\sqrt{t_0^2-x_0^2})+\frac{x_0}{\sqrt{t_0^2-x_0^2}}\sqrt{t_0^2-x_0^2}=t_0 \alpha/2  +x_0$$

and as for the second term there, I might be wrong but:

$$\chi_{x'} = \psi_{x'} = \psi_x \frac{\partial x}{\partial x'} = \frac{t_0}{\sqrt{t_0^2-x_0^2}} \psi_x $$

So shouldn't it be $\alpha t_0 \psi_x$, instead of $(\alpha t_0+x_0) \psi_x$.

I guess I missed something.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: I think this is more suited for Physics SE.

Comment: Ok, I posted my question there as well.

Comment: @MathematicalPhysicist: one or the other. If you don't get an answer on one, it can be migrated. Unless you give all the pertinent equations, Physics.SE members are more likely to have the book you're working in. Even so, it would be best to give a complete statement of your question, not relying on others to have the book.

Comment: The scans of the relevant pages are in the links from mediafire, Can't you see the pics?